# Android Studio jdbc y base de datos remota en internet

Tags: mysql

Bueno la razón de este post es para preguntar a los que ya lo hayan intentado y/o los que tengan curiosidad como yo. 
Bueno estoy creando una aplicación en android que sirve para ejecutar comandos de SQL en un servidor remoto de MYSQL instalado en una plataforma de CENTOS7,mi servidor ya fue configurado para aceptar conexiones remotas a dicho servidor.
La pregunta es ¿JDBC de MYSQL solo sirve para trabajar en bases de datos de manera local es decir la aplicacion solo funcionaria en local exclusivamente? He visto varios post diciendo que lo mejor es usar web service y php cosa que ya habia hecho en otros servidores remotos,pero al tener acceso al servidor lo mas lógico sería usar el propio conector y comandos Mysql dentro de android studio.
Al tratar de  crear una conexion;

```
conexionmysql=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://ip.ip.ip.ip:3306/mibasededatos" ,"unusuariovaaqui" ,"unacontraseñax");
```

al tratar de ejecutar el comando que establece conexión al servidor obtengo esto:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: 
>   Could not create connection to database server.

Bueno esa es mi pequeña pregunta si alguien lo ha intentado dígame como lo hizo.

Comment: Creo que vas por el camino equivocado. Si la base de datos está en el servidor , delega al servidor todo lo que sea conexión , consulta y obtención de datos (recomendaría PDO). Luego a través de Android tu solo haces la petición de lo que quieres y el servidor te manda los datos en forma de un JSON por ejemplo. ¿Qué sentido tiene gestionar la conexión desde Android si la BD no está en Android sino en el servidor? Todas las API modernas funcionan así y tecnologías más modernas como Firebase también. Olvídate de JDBC para esto, ni es lo más rápido ni es lo mejor.

Comment: A. Cedano muchas gracias por la respuesta, creo que el metodo tradicional de JSON es lo mejor. En fin.

Comment: Hasta que no se invente otra JSON es lo mejor para esto porque es ligero y permite enviar información de forma ordenada. De hecho Firebase por ejemplo no usa bases de datos, sino que organiza los datos en objetos JSON.